# Как передать параметры запроса в VUE Js, не перезагружая выполнить methods?

Tags: vue.js, запрос, spa

Как лучше поступить в Vue js чтобы при нажатии кнопки search, передавались параметры запроса в URL и я мог выполнить methods(выполнить ajax на основе параметров), как при обычном submit но без перезагрузки страницы. В данном коде параметры передаются но clickBtn в моем случае не работает

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Введите критерии">

         <router-link
         tag="button"
        :to="{name: '', query: {search: search}}" @click="clickBtn"
    >Search</router-link>
    </form>
   <h1>{{searchG}}</h1>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            search: '',
            searchG: this.$route.query.search,
        }
    },

methods:{
    clickBtn(){
        console.log(333)
    }    
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы отрабатывал метод `clickBtn` нужно добавить модификатор `@click.native="clickBtn"`. Но можно поступить несколько по другому.

```
// search.vue

<template>
<div>
  <h1>Поиск</h1>
  <form class="search__form">
    <input type="text" class="search__input" v-model="query.s" />

    <button type="button" class="search__button" @click="initSearch">Найти</button>
  </form>
  <ul v-if="Boolean(results.length)">
    <li v-for="result in results">{{ result.title }}</li>
  </ul>
  <!--
    Тут можно использовать пагинатор, добавив в модель query поле page
    По клику менять query.page и запускать метод initSearch()
  -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = 'api/v1/articles'

export default {
  name: 'search',

  data() {
    return {
      // Модель результатов. Изначально пустой массив.
      results: [],
      // Модель запросов.
      query: {
        // Поисковая строка.
        // Берем значение из маршрута.
        s: this.$route.query.s,
        // Тут можно задать другие параметры, например:
        // page, order_column, order_direction
      },
    }
  },

  watch: {
    // Следим за изменением запроса `query` маршрута.
    '$route.query'() {
      this.fetch()
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    // Если при монтировании компонента
    // поисковая строка не пустая,
    // то выполняем запрос.
    if (this.query.s) this.fetch()
  },

  methods:{
    initSearch() {
      // Тут можно задать различные проверки.

      // Программно изменяем маршрут.
      // Наблюдатель отследит изменения в запросе.
      this.$router.replace({
        query: this.query
      })
    },

    async fetch() {
      // Можно обернуть в блок try...catch
      const response = await axios({
          url: API_URL,
          params: this.query,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        })

      this.results = response.data
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Для навигации из другого компонента:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" />

  <router-link
    tag="button"
    :to="{name: 'search', query: {s: search}}"
    >Найти</router-link>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но при переходе по ссылке по заданным параметрам не вызывается функция fetch(), тоесть работает только по клику кнопки button

Comment: ну вот я ввел параметры в input, кликнул по button, все сработало запрос отправился по ajax так же сформировались параметры запроса в URL как я и хотел и по идее при переходе по этому URL должен происходить такой же запрос(я же не просто так формировал этот URL с параметрами, а для того чтобы по нему можно было пройти). Я так понимаю что watch не отследит это, нужно смотреть в сторону хук -ов

Comment: например поделится ссылкой с теми параметрами, и человек при переходе по ней тоже получит данные не нажимая кнопки

Comment: @MaxStarterov, отредактировал. Различия удобнее смотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/977100/revisions)

Comment: вау круто, все работает, спасибо...а главное что я код понимаю

Comment: @MaxStarterov, если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его как решение.